# On CodeIgniter, how to repopulate a form only with correct values?

Tags: forms, validation, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, repopulation

Imagine a form like this:

```
<form action="test.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="firstname" value="<?=set_value('firstname')?>" />
    <input type="text" name="lastname" value="<?=set_value('lastname')?>" />
    <input type="text" name="email" value="<?=set_value('email')?>" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit_form" value="OK" />
</form>
```

If I submit an incorrect email, the CodeIgniter function will write "the field is not valid" and populate the invalid field with the wrong value.

I would like to keep the error message but not the wrong value (I prefer having an empty value). But I also want to keep the re-populating function for correct values.

**Here is what I get:**

[image: http://nsa21.casimages.com/img/2011/12/29//111229060041170572.jpg]

**Here is what I want:**

[image]

**[EDIT] SOLUTION FOUND** (thanks to Herr Kaleun and Matt Moore)

Example with the email field:

```
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="<?=!form_error('email')?set_value('email'):''?>" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the fields individually and have a logic like this.

If the error for a specific field is present, you can build a logic on top of that.

```
if ( form_error('email') != '' )
{
    $data['email_value'] = '';
}
else
{
    $data['email_value'] = set_value('email');
}

<form action="test.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="firstname" value="<?=set_value('firstname')?>" />
    <input type="text" name="lastname" value="<?=set_value('lastname')?>" />
    <input type="text" name="email" value="<?= $email_value; ?>" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit_form" value="OK" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

The Form_error is set when a form value errors out based on the validation. Judging by your use of the set_value function I assume you're using the built in form validation. You can check to see if the message for that field is set `if(form_error('fieldname') !=NULL)` and set the value based on that.

You may have to setup error messages for each field, which you should be doing anyway. Here is the guide that covers it: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#repopulatingform

```
<form action="test.php" method="post"> 
    <input type="text" name="firstname" value="<?if(form_error('firstname') != NULL){echo set_value('firstname');}?>" /> 
    <input type="text" name="lastname" value="<?if(form_error('lastname') != NULL){ echo set_value('lastname');}?>" /> 
    <input type="text" name="email" value="<?if(form_error('email') !=NULL){ echo set_value('email');}?>" /> 
    <input type="submit" name="submit_form" value="OK" /> 
</form>
```

***NOTE THIS CODE HAS NOT BEEN TESTED ***